# Inserting and removing values within a collection array

Tags: express, mongoose

I'm new to working with MongoDb using Express. I currently have a collection that has an array within an object. The array is meant to hold an unlimited number of values.

My question is when I add a new item to that array in the collection, do I always have to pass all the values in the object?

For example, with the following collection. Say I wanted to add a new contact.

```
{
   "owner": "Tom Smith",
   "age": "29",
   "contacts": [
      {
         "firstname": "Fred",
         "lastname": "Anderson",
         "age": "22"
      },
      {
         "firstname": "Linda",
         "lastname": "Smith",
         "age": "32"
      },
      {
         "firstname": "Tom",
         "lastname": "James",
         "age": "42"
      },
      {
         "firstname": "Cal",
         "lastname": "Hallaway",
         "age": "57"
      }
   ],
   "city": "New York"
}
```

Do I need to explicitly declare all my values in the object I pass to the end point?

Example:

```
obj.owner = 'Tom Smith';
obj.age = '29';
obj.contacts.firstname = 'Fred';
obj.contacts.lastname = 'Anderson';
obj.contacts.age = '22';
```

... etc.

and then add my new contact and push the full object to the endpoint to update?

Is there a way that I can just add a new contact without pushing all the data that already exists in the collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a new data in a nested attribute array:

```
Model.findOneAndUpdate({
          _id: 'THE ID OF YOUR GYUS'
        }, {
          $push: {
            contacts: {
              firstname: 'TOTO',
              lastname: 'TITI',
              age: 42,
            },
          },
        });
```